# How can I print the first name of the user after they login on PHP?

Tags: php, html

I'm doing a login page for php, and the login page requires their email and password, however when they first register, it requires their first name and last name. I'm trying to print their first name after they login but I keep getting "undefined variable firstname", but it was called to store the value in the registration so I'm not sure what happen. If it needs to be called in the login aspect too, I'm not sure where to call it, and I don't want the user to enter their firstname again in the login page, I just want to pull that data from the registration page and enter it when they login.

This is the code for the index page that the user is directed to after they login

```
    <?php  

session_start();

if(isset($_GET['logout'])){
    session_destroy();
    unset($_SESSION['email']);
    unset($_SESSION['firstname']);
    
    header("location: index.php");
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Illustrious Marketing</title>
    
    <!--Bootstrap Stylesheet-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-4.4.1-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css">

    <!--Font-->
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/4f2c3df144.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <!--Header Start-->
    <header>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-lg-2 col-xl-3">
                    <div class="btn-group">
                        <button class="btn border dropdown-toggle my-md-4 my-2 text-color" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">GYD</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-10 col-lg-5 col-xl-5 text-center">
                    <h2 class="my-md-3 site-title text-color">Illustrious Marketing</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 text-center col-lg-5 text-right col-xl-4 text-right">
                    <p class="my-md-4 header-links">
                        <?php 
                        if(isset($_SESSION['firstname'])); 
                        ?>
                        <a href="#" class="px-3"> Hello <?php echo $_SESSION['firstname']; ?></a>
                        <a href="#" class="px-1">Become a Seller</a>
                        <a href="index.php?logout='1'" class="px-2">Sign Out</a>
                        <? php endif ?>
                    </p>
                </div>
```

This is the code in the login server

```
<?php
session_start();

// variable declaration
$email    = "";
$errors = array();


// connect to database
$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'illustriousmarketing');

// REGISTER USER
if (isset($_POST['reg_user'])) {
    // receive all input values from the form
    $firstname = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['firstname']);
    $lastname = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['lastname']);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['email']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password']);

    // form validation: ensure that the form is correctly filled
    if (empty($firstname)) { array_push($errors, "First Name is required"); }
    if (empty($lastname)) { array_push($errors, "Last Name is required"); }
    if (empty($email)) { array_push($errors, "Email is required"); }
    if (empty($password)) { array_push($errors, "Password is required"); }


    // register user if there are no errors in the form
    if (count($errors) == 0) {
        $password = md5($password);//encrypt the password before saving in the database
        $query = "INSERT INTO loginform (`firstname`, `lastname`, `email`, `password`)
                  VALUES('$firstname', '$lastname', '$email', '$password')";
        mysqli_query($db, $query);

        $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
        $_SESSION['success'] = "You are now logged in";
        header('location: indexloginbuyer.php');
    }

}

// ...

// LOGIN USER
if (isset($_POST['login_user'])) {
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['email']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password']);

    if (empty($email)) {
        array_push($errors, "Email is required");
    }
    if (empty($password)) {
        array_push($errors, "Password is required");
    }

    if (count($errors) == 0) {
        $password = md5($password);
        $query = "SELECT * FROM loginform WHERE email='$email' AND password='$password'";
        $results = mysqli_query($db, $query);
        if (mysqli_num_rows($results) == 1) {   
            $_SESSION['firstname'] = $firstname;
            $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
            $_SESSION['success'] = "You are now logged in";
            header('location: indexloginbuyer.php');
        }else {
            array_push($errors, "Wrong email/password combination");
        }
    }
}
```

?>

[image: Error that I am getting]

Comment: You need to set the session variable before you can retrieve it. In the code you posted, that doesn't happen. you also need to call [session_start()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) before you can access the `$_SESSION` variable.

Comment: I have session start in the code for the login server, my registration and login was done in   the main "server" file, I just posted the snippet of the login code since that is what is being discussed. I'll post the entire code for the server, can you show me where I need to set the session variable after I do so?

Comment: Just set it in the same place you set the `email` and `success` session variables. The `session_start()` method needs to be called in your first code snippet before accessing the variables as well.

Comment: I'm no longer getting the error but the name still isn't displaying

Comment: Where are you actually setting the session variable for the first name? I still don't see it anywhere in your code.

Comment: Sorry I didn't update my code to match the changes I made, I just did that

Answer (score -1):

You should add

session_start(); // Start the session

to start session. After it you need to assign

$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);

$_SESSION['firstname'] = $row['firstname'];

inside the if block after you check user's credentials.

Comment: I'm no longer getting the error but it still isn't displaying the name :(

Comment: remove line $_SESSION['firstname'] = $firstname; and replace with $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);

$_SESSION['firstname'] = $row['firstname'];